# if else condiation on key name in terraform codes

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

as I knew, we can use [terraform count](https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/count) as if-else condiation, but that's for value.

Use sample of [Data Source: aws_secretsmanager_secret](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/secretsmanager_secret)

It has two keys: `name` or `arn`

My condiation is,

- if I got variable `secret_name`, it will use key `name`
- if I got variable `secret_arn`,  it will use key `arn`
- they can't be used at same time (I can control this by myself)

how to do that, something like this

```
data "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "this" {
  if count = length(var.secret_arn)
     arn = var.secret_arn
  else if count = length(var.secret_name)
     name = var.secret_name
  fi
}
```

Comment: Are you going to have `count` meta-argument or not? If not it shouldn't be hard to achieve that.

Comment: can be any way, never mind to use count or not

Answer (score 0):

You can alternate between `arn` and `name` as follows:

```
data "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "by-arn" {
  arn = length(var.secret_arn) > 0 ? var.secret_arn : null
  name = length(var.secret_name) > 0 ? var.secret_name : null
}
```

Comment: While this does literally answer the question given its content, I would hypothesize the question is ambiguous without the `variable` declaration blocks. While this does work if the default values are empty strings, it would not work if the default values were the `null` type (which is also possible). Therefore, if this does not work for you @Bill, then the question needs to be updated with the variable declaration blocks.

Comment: @marcin, as I said, you can't put both arn and name in same data source, they are `or` condition, not `and`. You still deal with the value, not the key

Comment: @Bill They are exclusive. It works exactly as you described. Only one value is possible. If you specify both, to code errors out. If you specify none of them, it errors out as well. It only works if you specify one of them.

Comment: @MattSchuchard Thanks Matt. But In my view the answer works exactly as OP requested. It is only valid if one value is given, not the second. If both values are not given, or both are given, it results in an error. OP does not request any user friendly validation messages nor has other conditions on the input variables. Otherwise you could take this forever, and keep adding condition for non-existing secret names, invalid ARN formats, permissions access issues, invalid characters in names, and more. But I agree that the OP's question is not clear to account for all possible use-cases.

Comment: @Marcin I believe you missed the point of the comment, which is that you answered the literal question posted and solved the problem in the question, but that the question may be not be fully representative of the situation, and therefore the answer may not solve the actual problem. In that situation the question would need to be updated.